# Medical leave due to stress and depression

Tags: work-environment

I am a caregiver.

I work 6 days a week from 8 to 8 and I already suffer with anxiety. I work with seniors who have Alzheimer's and dementia I have been feeling really stressed and slight depressed.

I want to take some time off from work but can't afford to. What can I tell my doctor?

Comment: I read "I cannot afford to" as "I don't get paid sick leave". Where are you located? There may be alternative options depending on locale.

Comment: I'm not surprised, given the hours you are working.  That's unreasonably long hours for what's bound to be a stressful job anyway.

Answer (score 12):

Tell your doctor what you told us. They will ask additional questions, and may recommend some medical leave time and/or may have other suggestions for stress management.

Comment: Yep, that's about all you can do